# What is the Imperial Navy rank structure and where was it inspired from?

Tags: star-wars

In reading *Thrawn* he receives a few ranks which I found interesting. He is a commodore and ultimately a grand admiral.

What was the rank structure in the Empire's navy? And what was the motivation/basis for this structure, particularly when I believe some of the ranks are different than existing ranks in most militaries?

Comment: I think these are two questions - one has an in-universe answer, and the other has an out of universe answer

Comment: Are Legends-only answers acceptable?

Comment: @Null prefer non-legends (I didn't tag this as [tag:legends]). I guess if there are no canonical answers legends would be fine.

Comment: @NKCampbell do you think it's worth splitting this into two questions?

Comment: I assumed you wanted an answer from canon since you didn't use the Legends tag, but I'm trying to confirm if [Essen's Legends-only answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/160221/31936) is acceptable or if it should be deleted.

Comment: @Null the answer you mentioned is completely wrong in the current Canon.  From the Thrawn novel, he was promoted to Captain **before** he was promoted to Commander.

Answer (score 3):

The (Legends) ranking system is described in *The Essential Guide to Warfare* by Del Rey (2012).

[image]

The guide describes the difference between positions and line ranks as following:

> **Position** is an officer's current assignment to a specific ship of
>   unit, as opposed to permanent rank. The positions of Warlord and High
>   Admiral are essentially honorary, normally held by Grand Admirals and
>   Moffs.
>
> **Line rank** is held by line officers, the men who command the bridge
>   crew, captain ships, and hoist their flag over fleets. There are very
>   few officers with permanent line ranks above senior captain (formally
>   known as captain of the line).

Out-of-universe, the inspiration seems to come from the military rank systems on Earth, with great influence of American and British systems. There are many similar rank names, with some fictional flavor added, of course.

There is a good list of naval officer ranks in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_officer_ranks).

Comment: Which Earth rank systems?

Comment: This is not tagged Legends so a Legends-only answer may not be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Is this supported by canonical references? Also, part of the reason I am asking is that there are multiple ranks which are never really used in Earth navies - such as senior lieutenant , grand admiral, and the fairly obsolete commodore title.

Comment: "Plack"? Did they make that up or is it a valid spelling of "plaque"?

Comment: @enderland The Wikipedia list of ranks includes both Grand Admiral and Commodore. In addition, there seems to be Senior Lieutenants in German, Russian, and Finnish armies, like mentioned [here]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senior_lieutenant). Like said, the Imperial ranking system is a mix of the ones on Earth; probably of the ones that *sounded* good.

Comment: Given Thrawn held the rank of Captain before being promoted to Commander, this answer is completely wrong, despite being accurate in legends.

Answer (score 0):

The Canon ranks are as follows:

- Ensign
- Lieutenant (Junior)
- Senior Lieutenant
- Captain
- Lt. Commander
- Commander
- Commodore
- Rear Admiral
- Vice Admiral
- Admiral
- Fleet Admiral
- Grand Admiral

In many Legends books, the ranks are slightly different:

- Ensign
- Lieutenant
- Lieutenant Commander
- Commander
- Captain
- Rear Admiral (then the ranks continue the same as they do in Canon)

In Canon, most officers holding the Captain rank only actually command smaller vessels (such as Gozanti-Class) or act as First Officers on Star Destroyers and do not actually command their own larger ships (such as Star Destroyers) until the rank of Lt. Commander or Commander.

Comment: Can you provide any sources for your findings? Do you have any source books or data books which support your ranking?

Answer (score -2):

It seems to me that the lowest rank was Crewman and then we only know officer ranks. Please someone, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Considering the question is about Grand Admiral Thrawn, it is about officer ranks.