# What does the colors mean for the Galactic Empire ranks?

Tags: star-wars

For a very long time I’ve been trying to figure this out WHAT does the red, blue, and sometimes yellow means on a Officer of the Empire? For example does red mean Command, or what about blue below?

[image]

Comment: Seems dupey. The other question doesn't really address the colour differences though; [What do the Imperial officer rank badges mean?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9789/what-do-the-imperial-officer-rank-badges-mean/9790#9790)

Comment: Well the colors has to mean something maybe a type of officer or what he learned idk what but the color is there for a reason.

Comment: [Wookieepedia - "Rank Insignia of the Empire"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_of_the_Galactic_Empire) / and [the ranks themselves](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_of_the_Galactic_Empire?file=Essential-Guide-To-Warefare-Imperial-Ranks.png)

Comment: I’ve already read through them and I can’t find anything about what does the color itself means..

Comment: Pablo Hidalgo pointed out that they don't mean a damn thing and are invariably wrong; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_plaque

Comment: I always thought they were cough drop supplies

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160215/what-is-the-imperial-navy-rank-structure-and-where-was-it-inspired-from

Comment: Reminds me of the old Imperial sailor's saying *"If the top is red, you'll soon be dead."*

Answer (score 2):

From *Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Dictionary*:

> **Imperial Insignia**
>
> A plaque with an arrangement of colored rectangles denotes rank. Sector-specific design schema creates a hodgepodge of non-uniform rankings.

**So it does signify rank, but there's no consistent meaning to the colors.**

---

A few of the plaques seen in other pages of that book:

- Director Krennic: Six Red blocks on top of Six Blue blocks (the book notes that this is the Fleet equivalence of admiral)
- Lieutenant Valdas: Two Red blocks followed by 1 Blue block
- Lieutenant (Jr Grade) Chasser: Two Blue blocks

Answer (score 1):

Republic/Galactic Officer Rank Insignia:

These were metal backings with color squares attached to said backing to signify officer ranking. The purpose of these insignia was to help other military personnel identify officers from a distance / to differentiate rank. These plaques were used by the Galactic Republic and the Galactic Empire. The First Order used shirt collar insignia, much like the United States Navy. The Republic and the Empire also used code cylinders that had special access codes and information.

The colors of the square were blue, red, and gold. **The different colors had no specific meaning, but different combinations created different meanings/insignia.**

Sources:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_plaque/Legends
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rank_insignia_of_the_Galactic_Empire/old_version

Comment: What is the source of this information?

Comment: Wookieepedia. Otherwise, it is common knowledge. In Star Wars Rebels, code cylinders are used in Season 2, I believe. (I'd have to fact check) You can also see plaque insignia on Republic Naval Officers in SWCW. And if I knew a meaning for the colors, I would of provided a source.